# Открытие страницы с другого файла

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Суть вот в чём: делаю кроссплатформенное приложение на `jQuery` и чтобы не громоздить одну страницу с парочкой тысяч кода завел отдельный js файл, в которой хранятся даташиты на транзисторы. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в файле `home.html`  открывало страницу из того самого `.js` файла. Приведу пример: у меня есть файл `home.html` и `transistors.js.`
Приведу отрывок кода `home.html` :

```
<div id="transistors" data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<h1>Transistors</h1></div>
<div data-role="content">
<ul id="custom-format-listview" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
<li>
<a href="#100DA025D" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-icon="home"           
data-iconpos="right">100DA025D</a></li></ul></div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
<a href="#home" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right">Home</a>
<a href="#home" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" 
style="float:right">Back</a></div></div>
```

Как видно блок `div` выступает в роли страницы в которой есть кнопка, которая вызывает блок с id= 100DA025D но этот блок у меня находится в файле `transistors.js` код которого:

```
<div data-role="page" id="100DA025D" data-title="Home">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed"><img src="img/logo.JPG" width="100%"></div>
<div data-role="content">
<a href="#datasheets" data-role="button" data-transition="flip" style="margin-top:2%">Datasheets</a>
<a href="#settings" data-role="button" data-transition="flip">Settings</a>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"><h4>Copyright by LGM</h4></div>
</div>
```

Теперь повторю вопрос. Как мне отобразить блок с `id=100DA025D` на странице `home.html`?

Comment: ничего непонятно.

Comment: "открывало страницу из того самого js файла" - это как?

Comment: так transistors.js это не js скрипт, что вы пытаетесь добиться ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фунцкия load() загружает html файл куда укажешь

> $("#div").load("transistors.html");

Comment: Задам глупый вопрос. А как это встроить в кнопку?

Comment: Кнопке надо привязать событие, и присвоить этому событию обработчик. В обработчике указать код. Получится кнопка:
<input type="button" onclick="doSmth()" />
и обработчике:
function doSmth(){
    $("#div").load("transistors.html");
}

Comment: хотел бы добавить, что вешать вызов обработчика прямо в код элемента кнопки не самая правильная идея, хотя работать будет, рекомендуется или в конце страницы или вначале (тогда на событие загрузки DOM страницы), т.е. допустим вначале
$(function(){
//если кнопка на странице не одна, то нужно ей добавить id или class для удобства выбора иначе просто выбираем первую кнопку в документе
 $('input[type="button"]:eq(0)').on('click', function(){
 $('#div').load('transistors.html');
 });
});

Comment: Хм, спасибо, вот этого не знал. А чем такой вариант лучше?